# Incompatible version of android studio with the Gradle version used

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

My android-studio version is the latest 2.1.3,and I am try to update gradle to gradle-3.0-all with plugin 2.2.0-beta3.
When I build it was ok but when run the ide report that "Incompatible version of android studio with the Gradle version used."
How can I resolve this?Should I use android-studio 2.2+?

Comment: why not just use corresponding gradle 2.14.1 and plugin 2.1.3?

Comment: Because 3.0 is much faster than 2.14.1..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use the latest stable version of the gradle distribution and the gradle plugin for android:

In `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
  }
```

In `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`:

```
distributionUrl = https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14-all.zip
```

Currently the version of gradle 3.x is not officially supported.

Comment: I solved it by myself...Clean and rebuild do the magic.Thanks anyway,accpeted your answer

Answer (score 0):

Android studio will notify you if Gradle plugin needs update. no need for doing it yourself.

Comment: Correct, Android Studio does notify you, offers to update, but then fails prompting me "Error:The versions of the Android Gradle plugin and Gradle are not compatible.". Leading me to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Some time it wont notify, like in my case